# How to append an object to an existing file (generics)?

Tags: java, file, object, generics, append

I'm having problems with appending a generic object within an existing file. This method is supposed to append the object to the existing file if the parameters are "true" and overwrites the entire file if "false". The "false" statement works perfectly fine, it overwrites the entire file but I can't seem to get the append one to work. It seems to do nothing at first glance but when I placed a simple System.out.println("test"); in the while (true) loop, it runs forever. How can I fix this?

```
public <T> void writeOneObject(T type, boolean append) throws NotSerializableException{

    if (append == true){
        //TODO
        if (file.exists ()){
            ObjectOutputStream ois = null;
            try{
                ois = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (file, true));
                while (true){
                   ois.writeObject(type);
                }
            }catch (StreamCorruptedException e){
            }catch (EOFException e){

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }finally{
                try{
                    if (ois != null) ois.close();
                }catch (StreamCorruptedException e){
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        }


    }
    else {  //overwrites the entire file
        try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(type);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I also have this inside the class:

```
class NoHeaderObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
      public NoHeaderObjectOutputStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        super(os);
      }
      protected void writeStreamHeader() {}
    }
```

Comment: You have to break your while loop with some condition otherwise it will go for toss.

Comment: Hmmm, `while (true){ ois.writeObject(type); }` will run until some kind of exception is thrown. It can hardly be a correct condition. What are you trying to achieve here with this loop?

Comment: I don't think you need loop as you are passing only one Object which you want to write.

Comment: @TAsk Even after I remove the while loop, a new object I write does not append to the existing file when I tested it.